# How to convert a procedural algorithm to a logic program?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, naming

How can I implement an algorithm in Prolog from its procedural description so as to best take advantage of the logical paradigm.

I sometimes find it hard to write a prolog program from a given procedural description of the algorithm. I give a concrete example of one attempt below. Notice I have predicates called innerforloop or convergedloop. This does not seem right and it is difficult to check that my implementation matches the algorithms description. Does this code match the description? What would be better names for these predicates? Or should the code be organised in a different way?

Example algorithm:  Train a perceptron classifier.

```
Input: labelled training data in D homogeneous coordinates;
       learning rate n.
Output: weight vector W defining classifier ŷ = sign(w⃗ ⋅  x⃗).

w⃗ <- 0;
converged <- false;
While converged = false do
  converged <- true;
  for i = 1 to |D| do
    if yiw⃗⋅x⃗i <0
    then
      w⃗<- w⃗+n * yi * x⃗i;
      converged <-false
    end
  end
end
```

My implementation:

```
perceptron(Pos,Neg,classifier(W,0)):-
   Pos =[OneExample|_],
   length(OneExample,NumberOfFeatures),
   populate_list(0,NumberOfFeatures,Zerovector),
   maplist(myappend([1]),Pos,PosClass),
   maplist(myappend([-1]),Neg,NegClass),
   append(PosClass,NegClass,Examples),
   convergedloop(Examples,Zerovector,W).

convergedloop(Examples,Inputvector,OutputVector):-
  innerforloop(Examples,Inputvector,UpdateVector),
  check_converged(Examples,Inputvector,UpdateVector,OutputVector).

check_converged(_Examples,W1,W2,W2):-W1=W2.
check_converged(Examples,W1,W2,W3):-
  dif(W1,W2),
  convergedloop(Examples,W2,W3).

innerforloop([],W,W).
innerforloop(ExamplesWithClass,W1,WFin):-
  ExamplesWithClass =[One|Rest],
  update_weight(One,W1,W2),
  innerforloop(Rest,W2,WFin).

learning_rate(0.1).

update_weight(Example_with_class,W1,W2):-
  misclassified(W1,Example_with_class,true),
  learning_rate(N),
  append(Example,[Class|[]],Example_with_class),
  Scalar is N *Class,
  scalar_multiplication(Scalar,Example,ExampleScaled),
  vector_addition(W1,ExampleScaled,W2).

update_weight(Example_with_class,W,W):-
  misclassified(W,Example_with_class,false).

misclassified(W,Example_with_class,TrueFalse):-
  append(Example,[Class|[]],Example_with_class),
  dot_product(Example,W,Dot),
  multiply(Dot,Class,Value),
  (   Value =<0->TrueFalse=true;TrueFalse=false).

%%%background predicates
myappend(Y,X,Z):-
  append(X,Y,Z).

multiply(X,Y,Z):-
  Z is X*Y.

vector_addition(X,Y,Z):-
  maplist(my_plus,X,Y,Z).

dot_product(V1,V2,Dot):-
  maplist(multiply,V1,V2,VMul),
  sumlist(VMul,Dot).

scalar_multiplication(S,X,SX):-
  maplist(multiply(S),X,SX).

populate_list(Pop,Length,ListPoped):-
  length(List,Length),findall(X,(member(X,List),X=Pop),ListPoped).

%%%Data
linear_sep_data(Pos,Negs,All):-
All=[
    [1.5998426,0.52985437,1],
            [0.25065517,1.30425162,1],
            [0.76148911,0.60419602,1],
            [0.75591032,-0.78994764,1],
            [1.63605539,0.9225655,1],
            [2.70520379,0.93285704,1],
            [1.82870703,2.34804646,1],
            [-0.08549264,0.99868399,1],
            [0.44906531,0.90555838,1],
            [0.49966187,1.59299327,1],
            [1.00003726,-0.13822094,1],
            [1.67943676,1.25283262,1],
            [-1.00158649,2.73839505,1],
            [3.32539035,-0.39289509,1],
            [2.17885898,0.05984356,1],
            [1.85977529,0.76782626,1],
            [1.34470454,0.18312675,1],
            [0.5974872,0.1228956,1],
            [-1.52394333,-1.24558361,-1],
            [-2.48452861,-1.91070328,-1],
            [-1.04605257,-2.55270759,-1],
            [1.02370408,-1.67944911,-1],
            [-0.80492117,-1.49215482,-1],
            [-1.64954319,-3.41635041,-1],
            [-2.35543276,-0.37750433,-1],
            [-0.32384031,-2.08235145,-1],
            [-1.56576954,-1.22018985,-1],
            [-1.27853841,-1.28469686,-1],
            [-1.97696119,0.23717806,-1],
            [-1.78965834,-1.09026084,-1]],
findall(Instance,(member(InstanceC,All),append(Instance,[1|[]],InstanceC)),Pos),
findall(Instance,(member(InstanceC,All),append(Instance,[-1|[]],InstanceC)),Negs).
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this algorithm is doing in detail (some of the formatting is wonky, *e.g.*, `yiw⃗⋅x⃗i <0`). But in general, I try to understand what an algorithm is doing first and determine if there's a relational way to look at it. You can just try to "copy the algorithm", but then just end up with an imperative implementation in Prolog.

Comment: yi is either 1 for positive class of an example i, or -1 for a negative  example i. w⃗ is a weight vector that we are learning, the length the same number of features.  x⃗i is an instance i, it is a vector of features. e.g. example 1:
[1.5998426,0.52985437,1], x1 is [1.5998426,0.52985437] and yi is 1. 
w⃗⋅x⃗i is the dot product of  w⃗ and x⃗i. I am not sure how to format this to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key insight for naming things in Prolog is that a logic program defines **relations** between entities. Ideally, predicate names give you an indication about which entities are described by each argument.

Hence, a name like `forloop` or `innerloop` correctly feels **wrong** to you in this case: From a name like `forloop` (or more readable: `for_loop`), we would rather expect for example a syntactic description of what a "for loop" is, but certainly not the actual *computation* that the loop is supposed to carry out.

Imperative algorithms describe a sequence of destructive **modifications** of a global state. To translate an imperative algorithm to the declarative paradigm, we change our viewpoint and instead describe **relations between states**.

We use the following naming convention, which is useful in many programs: `S0` denotes the initial state. `S1` denotes the state after one step of the computation. `S2`, `S3` etc. denote further states, and, at last, `S` denotes the **final state**.

Consider now the concrete example you cite:

The essence of the algorithm in imperative terms is to repeatedly modify a state until a final state is reached. One way to describe this sequence of state transition in the declarative paradigm is as follows:

```
state0_state(S0, S) :-
     state_next(S0, S1),
     state0_state_(S0, S1, S).

state0_state_(S0, S, S) :-
     close_enough(S0, S).
state0_state_(S0, S1, S) :-
     not_close_enough(S0, S1),
     state0_state(S1, S).
```

Where `state_next/2`, `close_enough/2` and `not_close_enough/2` must be supplied by you. I leave this as an exercise. Note that the predicate `state0_state/2` is named in such a way that it is clear what each argument denotes. With some thought, you will likely find more descriptive names for this, such as `training0_training/2`.

Depending on how well you do this, we observe one valuable advantage of the declarative paradigm: The code can be used **in all directions**. This means for example that you can also post the most general query:

```
?- state0_state(S0, S).
```

and ideally obtain as answers states that are in this relation.

One more tip for naming predicates: **Avoid imperatives**. Imperatives make little sense in the declarative paradigm, because many predicates can be used in several directions, and an imperative always implies a single direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess what I am confused about is nested loops in algorithms.
The over all relation is between some data and a learnt vector so maybe something like:  data_perceptron(Data,Perceptron). Where preceptron is the weight vector.

A single update of the vector is a relation between an example the old weight and the new weight. so update_weight/3 should be renamed: example_weight0_weight1/3. I think that I should be able to replace the for loop with something like foldl(example_weight0_weight1,Data,Weight0,Weight).

Comment: The for loop is a relation between an initial vector and a single pass through the data. But cant quiet figure it out. In any case I would then need to have the converged loop around that? So the foldl section could be the equivalent of your state_next/2?  and close_enough/2 is when there is convergence?

Comment: Yes, this definitely goes in the right direction, and keeps the wording general enough so that you can use everything, at least in principle, in all directions. `close_enough/2` is meant to be true **iff** we consider the state converged.

Comment: Also note that in practice, this purity is sometimes sacrificed for performance reasons, and impure constructs like if-then-else etc. are used to impurely limit the relations to certain usage modes. Do not let this distract you though: The principle remains in both cases that you reason about successive states, and the predicate names should ideally make clear what each argument is.